Pyhton: Error forecasting ARMA model for Log Returns
I am trying to do an ARMA forecast to forecast future values of returns for a specific stock ticker. I keep getting range errors and other errors that dont let me forecast any values.
All the steps work according to plan except when it is time to plot the returns and the forecast.
Anyone know what could solve the issue:
Ill past code and error message:
forecast = model.predict(start=len(data_train), end=len(data))

data_forecast = pd.concat([data_train, data_test, pd.Series(forecast, index=data.iloc[len(data_train):].index)])

data_forecast.plot(label='Original Returns')
plt.plot(data_forecast.index[len(data_train):], forecast, label='Forecast')
plt.title('Log Returns with ARMA Forecast')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-6adfef884367> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 
      5 data_forecast.plot(label='Original Returns')
----> 6 plt.plot(data_forecast.index[len(data_train):], forecast, label='Forecast')
      7 plt.title('Log Returns with ARMA Forecast')
      8 plt.legend()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs, ambiguous_fmt_datakey)
    502 
    503         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 504             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    505                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    506         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (0,) and (1,)

I have changed range subtracted one for the test data and tried over and over with chatgpt, I can't get it to work.
